# How is n-sigma is related to (Student) t-test?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, standard-deviation

By n-sigma I mean anything like three- or six-sigma. Both Student's test and n-sigma seem to be related to confidence intervals. I see that the t-test is done for some confidence intervals expressed in %, e.g. 95% where as n-sigma means that you take interval = n standard deviations. So, it seems that the translation from one to another is straightforward. But I don't see anybody discussing it.

Answer (score 1):

A confidence interval and a test aren't quite the same thing, but they are very much related, and often involve some of the same steps of calculation, though used in a different way. It's possible to turn CIs into tests ("Is the hypothesized value inside the $1-\alpha$ confidence region?") and vice versa ("What set of values of the parameter(s) lead us to fail to reject at level $\alpha$?"), though the latter is sometimes called a consonance interval (or consonance region for more than a single parameter).

A confidence interval for say a mean of a normal-distribution will be based on a pivotal quantity like $Q=\frac{\mu - \bar x}{s/\sqrt{n}}$. This quantity has a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

For example, consider a sample of size 5. The density of $Q$, a $t$ with 4 degrees of freedom, will look like so:

[image: t4 density]

I have marked on the positions ($\pm 2.776$) that enclose 95% of that probability.

That is, if we knew $\mu$, 95% of the occasions for which we compute a $Q$ for a sample of size 5 with normal data, $Q$ would lie between $-2.776$ and $2.776$.

$$-2.776 \leq \frac{\mu - \bar x}{s/\sqrt{n}} \leq 2.776$$

$$-2.776\,{s/\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu - \bar x \leq 2.776\,{s/\sqrt{n}}$$

$$ \bar x -2.776\,{s/\sqrt{n}} \leq \mu \leq \bar x + 2.776\,{s/\sqrt{n}}$$

That is, an interval of 2.776 estimated standard errors* about the mean is the interval size in this case.

*(standard deviations of the distribution of the mean)

As the coverage of the interval changes, or the size of the sample changes, those values change. They come from the [inverse of the cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_.28quantile_function.29) of the relevant $t$ distribution; for a $1-\alpha$ interval, you find the value that cuts off an upper tail area of $\alpha/2$; the lower tail follows by symmetry.

In large samples, the $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom approaches a normal distribution, and those critical values come from the inverse of the normal distribution function. (1.96 is the corresponding value for a 95% confidence interval for a normal distribution).

Indeed, as $n$ approaches infinity, the distribution of the sample mean approaches a normal distribution as a result of the central limit theorem, and from Slutsky's theorem the statistic $Q$ also approaches a normal distribution.

In such samples, to compute the number of standard errors (such as the 1.96 mentioned above) for a normal distribution, you use the inverse normal cdf.

Conversely to all the above, to find the coverage of an interval of half-width being a given number of standard errors, we use the [distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)

Comment: You say pivotal quantity =(−\bar{})/(s/√n) has a t-distribution with −1 degrees of freedom. How do we prove this?