# One sided confidence interval for the mean

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I want to test the following hypothesis:
$$ H_0: \mu \geq \mu_0 \\
H_a: \mu < \mu_0.$$

I use one sample t-test:
$$t_0 = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}.$$
Since under the alternative we expect that $\bar{X}$ is small, we should reject for small values of $t_0$. Thus, given that the size of the test is equal to $\alpha$, we reject if
$$t_0 \leq -t_{1-\alpha}(n-1).$$
My aim is to construct a confidence interval for $\mu$. Given my results, can I construct a confidence interval for $\mu$ based on the fact that we don't reject if
$$t_0 > -t_{1-\alpha}(n-1),$$
thus the confidence interval should be constructed by solving the following inequality
$$ \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} > -t_{1-\alpha}(n-1)?$$
I am not sure that my way of reasoning is consistent since I use t-test (with $\mu_0$) in order to construct the rejection region and I use $\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ (with $\mu$ instead of $\mu_0$) in order to determine the confidence interval.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71902/805) of some use.